# Getting position or index value of an item in an eloquent collection

Tags: php, loops, foreach, laravel-8

Please I need your help. I am trying to get the position of students from an eloquent collection array.

```
$class_subject_marks_for_position = 
    App\Models\StudentMarks::where('year_id',$mark->year_id)
            ->where('class_id',$mark->class_id)
            ->where('exam_type_id',$mark->exam_type_id)                 
            ->where('assign_subject_id',$mark->assign_subject_id)
            ->pluck('marks')->toArray();
```

This will return an array of values like 55, 77, 99 etc. score of all students

I also have a second variable

```
$student_subject_marks_for_position = 
    App\Models\StudentMarks::where('year_id',$mark->year_id)
            ->where('class_id',$mark->class_id)
            ->where('exam_type_id',$mark->exam_type_id)
            ->where('assign_subject_id',$mark->assign_subject_id)
            ->where('student_id',$mark->student_id)
            ->value('marks');
```

This will return a value like 55. for that particular student.

Now I would like to have another variable or something like that, that will get the position of 55  in the first variable. that is will return something like 1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Perhaps https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php ?

Answer (score 0):

index of 55 in {55, 77, 99} is 0th index which you can get from below code

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($class_subject_marks_for_position); $i++){
    if($student_subject_marks_for_position == $class_subject_marks_for_position[$i]){
        $position = $i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Explain your code.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I have been battling with the code since without getting the required results.

Comment: by position you mean where 55 stands compared to 77 and 99?  @EMMANUELTSWAM

Comment: What I am trying to to is to get the indexOf()  55 in the array 55, 77, 99 but using the variables

Comment: Yes were 55 stands.  that is it's index or something like that in the array [55, 77, 99].

Comment: the 1st two are db queiries..... and 3rd can only be achieved by comparing the 1st 2 variables....either you're confused or not able to properly explain what outcome exactly you want.  Because index of 55 in {55, 77, 99} is 0th and position after comparison is 3rd...

Comment: But variable are from database querries. The first returns an array while the second will return a value. I want to get the index of the value in the array. Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the comment by @aynber answer your question..I don't understand what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) function.

> Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful

```
$index_of_55_in_first_array = array_search(
    $student_subject_marks_for_position, //The value to search
    $class_subject_marks_for_position) //The array
```

Also, validate if the index is !== to FALSE because 0 is a valid index but also a falsy value.

> This function may return Boolean false, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to false (0).